# How many ways can 20 coins be selected from four containers filled with pennies, nickels, dimes, and quarters?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many ways can 20 coins be selected from four containers filled with pennies, nickels, dimes, and quarters? (Each container is filled with only one type of coin)

So, 20 slots and four choices per each slot, right? First slot, I can choose P, N, D, or Q. I move on to slot 2 and do the same thing. This results in ${4}^{20}$, which is horribly incorrect.

Your help is appreciated!

Comment: Please see Stars and Bars (Combinatorics), Wikipedia, or the many Stars and Bars questions/answers on MSE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine that there are $4$ containers labelled $P,N,D,Q$ and you drop $20$ blank coins in any which way into the $4$ containers which magically become pennies, nickels, dimes, or quarters depending on which container you drop them.

This, then, is a typical [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) problem, $\binom{20+4-1}{4-1}=1771$

Answer (score 1):

Let $p$, $n$, $d$, and $q$ be, respectively, the number of pennies, nickels, dimes, and quarters selected.  Then
$$p + n + d + q = 20$$
A particular solution corresponds to the insertion of three addition signs in a row of twenty ones.  For instance,
$$1 1 1 1 + 1 1 1 1 1 + 1 1 + 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1$$
corresponds to $p = 4$, $n = 5$, $d = 2$, and $q = 9$, while
$$+ 1 1 1 1 1 1 + 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 + 1 1 1 1 1$$
corresponds to $p = 0$, $n = 6$, $d = 9$, and $q = 5$.  Thus, the number of ways the pennies, nickels, dimes, and quarters can be selected is the number of ways three addition signs can be inserted into a row of twenty ones, which is
$$\binom{20 + 3}{3} = \binom{23}{3}$$
since we must choose which three of the $23$ symbols (three addition signs and twenty ones) will be addition signs.

Answer (score 1):

It does make quite a difference if the coins are taken *in order*, in which case your solution is right; or *order is irrelevant*, then you have to use another technique. Other answers provide the solution via [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)): Represent the $20$ coins by a star $*$ each, separating types of coin by bars $\mid$. Thus you have a sequence of $20$ stars and $3 = 4 - 1$ bars separating groups, for a total of $\binom{20 + 4 - 1}{4 - 1}$ possibilities (select the positions of the bars among all positions).